# drop foreign key without name Oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints, alter

I want to ask a very basic question here.
We may/may not name a constraint while creating a table or after creating the table.
Suppose I chose not to name the foreign key constraint.

The table is having no records.

Can I delete the foreign key name without naming it.

I know how to get name of foreign key and then delete using it like

```
alter table my_table drop constraint fk_name;
```

but I want to delete/drop the foreign key constraint without mentioning its name.

Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *but i want to delete/drop the foreign key constraint without mentioning its name.*

That's not possible. The dropping a foreign key constraint *requires* a name. However you can find out the system generated name:

```
select constraint_name
from user_constraints
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
  and constraint_type = 'R';
```

Will show you all foreign keys defined on the table `MY_TABLE`. Using that statement you can even generate the necessary DDL statement:

```
select 'alter table "'||table_name||'" drop constraint "'||constraint_name||'";'
from user_constraints
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
  and constraint_type = 'R';
```

Save the output of that select into a file and you have the statement(s) to drop all foreign keys from that table.